# Regex exec only returning first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement the following regex search found on [golfscript syntax page](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/syntax.html).

```
var ptrn = /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|'(?:\\.|[^'])*'?|"(?:\\.|[^"])*"?|-?[0-9]+|#[^\n\r]*|./mg;
input = ptrn.exec(input);
```

Input is only ever the first match of the regexp. for example:
`"hello" "world"` should return `["hello", "world"]` but it only returns `["hello"]`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is only able to return a single match result at once.

In order to retrieve multiple matches you need to run `exec` on the expression object multiple times. For example, using a simple while loop:

```
var ptrn = /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|'(?:\\.|[^'])*'?|"(?:\\.|[^"])*"?|-?[0-9]+|#[^\n\r]*|./mg;

var match;
while ((match = ptrn.exec(input)) != null) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

This will log all matches to the console.

Note that in order to make this work, you need to make sure that the regular expression has the [`g` (global) flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters). This flag makes sure that after certain methods are executed on the expression, the [`lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) is updated, so further calls will start *after* the previous result.

The regular expression will also need to be declared *outside* of the loop (as shown in the example above). Otherwise, the expression object would be recreated on every iteration and then the `lastIndex` would obviously reset every time, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is an infinite loop. Don't use

Comment: @Pian0_M4n `RegExp.exec` returns `null` if it doesn’t find another match. Note that you will need to declare the regular expression (`ptrn`) *outside* of the loop so you don’t recreate it on every iteration (resetting the last index).

Comment: "n order to retrieve multiple matches you need to run exec on the expression object multiple times." isn't really true.  The next answer from Eadel is a better answer to the question (using string.match(regex) rather than regex.exec

Answer (score 34):

It is possible to call `match` method on the string in order to retrieve the whole collection of matches:

```
var ptrn = /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|'(?:\\.|[^'])*'?|"(?:\\.|[^"])*"?|-?[0-9]+|#[^\n\r]*|./mg;
var results = "hello world".match(ptrn);
```

`results` are (according to the regular expression):

```
["hello", " ", "world"]
```

[`match` spec is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: This is what I was looking for when I searched, thank you! A follow up question though: is it possible to do this for a regx with more than one match group? i.e. `"hello world hello world".match(/\S+ \S/g)`  

I would accept output in a 1D or 2D array.

Comment: Wouldn't `OR` operator `|` be enough? E.g. `"cat dog cat tiger dog".match(/(cat)|(dog)/g)` will produce `["cat", "dog", "cat", "dog"]`. This is 1D array. What is the desired output in your example?

Comment: Perhaps I should've given a less general example. Specificically I'm trying to parse an OBJ file which contains information about mesh faces in lines of the following form: `f 3/5/4 5/13/4 2/2/3 4/6/3` 

In my case, there may or may not be a number in the middle of the slashes, but if there is is I'd like to ignore it. So I'd like to do something like `/ (\d+)\/.*\/(\d+) /g` to extract just the ends of the slashed items.

Comment: There might be a better solution, but I would use something like this... `"3/5/4 5/13/4 2/2/3 4/6/3".match(/(\/(\d+)(?!(\d+|\/))|((^|\s)\d+))/g)`. This will return `["3", "/4", " 5", "/4", " 2", "/3", " 4", "/3"]`, you can distinguish thirs numbers by cheching for slash and space. This regex uses negative lookahead, that checks that numbers are not followed with slash. It works for last symbols only. The second part of pattern, that goes after `|` operator looks for numbers, that have newline or whitespace before them. I checked only on your example, so check on more data if you will use it.

Answer (score 2):

I did not get what is meant by `"hello" "world"` in your question, is it user input or regex but I was told that RegExp object has a state -- its `lastIndex` position that it starts the search from. It does not return all the results at once. It brings only the first match and you need to resume `.exec` to get the rest of results starting from lastIndex position:

```
const re1 = /^\s*(\w+)/mg; // find all first words in every line
const text1 = "capture discard\n me but_not_me" // two lines of text
for (let match; (match = re1.exec(text1)) !== null;) 
      console.log(match, "next search at", re1.lastIndex);
```

prints

```
["capture", "capture"] "next search at" 7
[" me", "me"] "next search at" 19
```

The functional JS6 way to build iterator for your results is here

```
RegExp.prototype.execAllGen = function*(input) {
    for (let match; (match = this.exec(input)) !== null;) 
      yield match;
} ; RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(input) {
  return [...this.execAllGen(input)]}
```

Please also note how, unlike [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283091/6267925), much more nicely I used `match` variable enclosed in the `for`-loop.

Now, you can capture your matches easily, in one line

```
const matches = re1.execAll(text1)

log("captured strings:", matches.map(m=>m[1]))
log(matches.map(m=> [m[1],m.index]))
for (const match of matches) log(match[1], "found at",match.index)
```

which prints

```
"captured strings:" ["capture", "me"]

[["capture", 0], ["me", 16]]
"capture" "found at" 0
"me" "found at" 16
```